# Importing strings in react instead of variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

What does it mean when you import a string in react? For example `import 'firebase/auth';` does this become a variable that I can use? How is this different from something like `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`

Comment: You're not importing a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Thank you for the answer importing a string with the relative path to a file only imports the module for it's side effects without importing any of it's actual values.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: To clarify, you're not importing a string. The string is the name of the module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute url to the .js file containing the module

Answer (score 0):

Importing a string with the relative path to a file only imports the module for it's side effects without importing any of it's actual values.

[Mozilla Web Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)